# Problema con api rest full en .net 6

Tags: sql-server, api, .net, asp.net-core, dapper

Cuento con el siguiente problema, cada uno de los elementos json del value vienen vacios

[image]

pero al debuggear en el controller del api aparece de esta forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿que creen que estaría pasando?

Algo me dice que puede ser por el contentType que dice "null" pero no se como cambiarlo, o los candaditos en cada atributo del objeto

La clase Usuario es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestra la clase usuario por favor

Comment: Listo, ahi la agregué en la parte inferior

Comment: Las imágenes de código, apoyan poco y disminuyen el % de obtener una respuesta, para aumentar el % de obtener una respuesta, coloca código en forma de texto, aquí una serie de recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: En C# el modificador de acceso por defecto es **private**; no puedes ver las propiedades porque están privadas. Por eso ves el candado. Añade public a cada una de las props e intenta de nuevo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenian razon, solo debia colocar public en cada atributo de las entidades ya que no estaba probando desde una base de datos local, sino en un servidor (si fuera local, no fuera necesario esos public)